# Change image in an array with an onComplete event in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am using a third-party component (timer) from https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer

I am trying to change the image each time my countdown timer completes. I was thinking of using a count with useState that increases it by 1 each time in the array. I'm not sure, I am relatively new to React-Native.

If you need to see more of my code I have uploaded it to GitHub at:
https://github.com/JRyanSaunders/Fitness-App

```html
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  Animated,
} from "react-native";
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-native-countdown-circle-timer";

export default function WorkoutTimer() {
  const Exercise = new Array(10);
  exercise[1] = "../assets/e1.jpg";
  exercise[2] = "../assets/e2.jpg";
  exercise[3] = "../assets/e3.jpg";
  exercise[4] = "../assets/e4.jpg";
  exercise[5] = "../assets/e5.jpg";
  exercise[6] = "../assets/e6.jpg";
  exercise[7] = "../assets/e7.jpg";
  exercise[8] = "../assets/e8.jpg";
  exercise[9] = "../assets/e9.jpg";
  exercise[10] = "../assets/e10.jpg";
  var num = 0;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CountdownCircleTimer
        isPlaying
        duration={60}
        size={240}
        colors={"#7B4FFF"}
        onComplete={() => {
          // do stuff here
          return [true, 1500]; // repeat animation in 1.5 seconds
        }}
      >
        {({ remainingTime, animatedColor }) => (
          <Animated.Text style={{ color: animatedColor }}>
            {remainingTime}
          </Animated.Text>
        )}
      </CountdownCircleTimer>
    // image stuff
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a functional component, the function is being re-run everytime it renders. This means that the value of `num` (in `var num = 0`) is reseted, and it's always 0.

The best solution here, as you mentioned, is to use the state. You can imagine your state as what defines the data of your component. Your component decides what to show according to the state.

You can, for example, save the count in a state variable (using useState) and set the image according to the value in this state (like `image={exercise[count]}`). Whenever the `onComplete` is called, you can set it there (augmenting the count by 1).

Another optimization can be to have the array of images out of the component. This would stop re-creating the array images on every render.

For more information on state, you can check the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: Your response was invaluable to me thank you so much!